# How do I make irregular shape in CSS

Tags: css

I wanna make this shape ( the black color one, on the left side ) : https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/10535419?key=066637f6e5d498e80eb0bdee9eee8372

My idea is to create a ***triangle down shape*** and scale it, then use `transform:translate()` to move the shape. Is there any better or easier way to got this shape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `clip-path` this [website](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) is a great tool to help you get the hang of it, in your case you would need something like this

```css
.shape {
width : 250px;
height : 400px;
background-color : #1a1a1a;
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="shape">
</div>
```